# Why doesn't circular referencing in objects use infinite memory?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I was creating a deep cloning object prototype

```
Object.prototype.clone = function() {
    const clonedObject = {};
    for (objectKeys in this) {
            if (typeof this[objectKeys] !== "object") {
                if (objectKeys === "clone") {
                    continue;
                }
                clonedObject[objectKeys] = this[objectKeys];
            } else {
                if (!hasCircularDependency) {
                    clonedObject[objectKeys] = this[objectKeys].clone();
                } else {
                    throw RangeError("Attempting to clone this object results in the Maximium call stack size");
                }
            }
    }
    return clonedObject;
};

function hasCircularDependency(obj) {
    try {
        JSON.stringify(obj);
    } catch(e) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and I tried cloning the window object, but I was confronted by a maximum call stack error due to circular referencing.

so I was wondering, why doesn't circular referencing use infinite memory?

after all, memory must store a reference of the parent object, then store a reference of the child object, which stores a reference of the parent object. This goes on to infinity and natively, one would think that this is true. so how does javascript handle references of circular referencing?

Comment: Circular reference does not require infinite memory. But if you try to iterate through it will never end and your stack will overflow.

Comment: @PM77-1 but why doesn't it require infinite memory? you did not answer my question

Comment: If you need to draw a circle you will not need an infinite supply of chalk. But if you try to walk until you reach the end you will never reach it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Careful with the concept of references. Because there is an infinite, walkable chain, does not mean there are infinite objects.

Let's take a simple circular dependency. Three objects (A, B, C) each one referring to the next one in the chain, like so:

[image]

In memory, this actually looks like the following:

- Object A, links to object C
- Object C, links to object B
- Object B, links to object A

Each object effectively has itself, and a pointer to the next in the chain.

It is only when you **walk** this cycle that you end up consuming infinite memory, unless you keep track of where you have already been.

There are algorithms to detect and (sometimes, if possible) break such cycles. They're used a lot when dealing with dependency management problems. [Tarjan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) is one of them.

Answer (score 5):

A reference is just a pointer, not a copy of the original object. So the circular reference is essentially just a number, which contains the location in memory of the the object.

It's the same reason we don't need an infinite number of contact lists if I have your phone number in my contact list, and you have my phone number in yours.

Comment: thanks, it seems I need to learn low-level programming concepts to deeply understand why this is